# Building event list from Firebase for table_calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

I am trying to make a list of calendar events show up below the table_calendar widget. I pull the events from a Firebase db. I want the list to appear when I click on a day in the calendar that has events associated with it.

When I execute the code, I can execute the query but that is all that runs. The execution is returned to the code where the function is called. This is the code executed when a day is tapped on the calendar.

```
void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay,
      [List<Events>? events]) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      });
      //_selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(selectedDay, events));
    }
    _buildEventList();
  }
```

[image]

The code for building the listview of events is here:

```
Widget _buildEventList() {
    final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
          .collection('events')
          .where('eventDate',
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(
                  _focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, _focusedDay.day))
          .where('eventDate',
              isLessThan: DateTime(
                  _focusedDay.year, _focusedDay.month, _focusedDay.day + 1))
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
              child: Text(
            'Loading...',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ));
        } else {
          var doc = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: doc.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    title: Text(
                      '${doc[index]['eventName'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                        text:
                            '${DateFormat('EE MM-dd-yyyy').format(doc[index]['eventDate'])}\n'
                            '${DateFormat('h:mm a').format(doc[index]['eventStartTime'])}, '
                            'Duration: ${doc[index]['eventDuration'] ?? 'n/a'} minutes',
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                '\n${doc[index]['eventDescription'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                color: Colors.blueGrey),
                          )
                        ])),
                    onTap: () {
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewEvent(false);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddEventScreen()));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The documents in the db exist and I run basically the same query to put markers on the calendar itself. It seems like the query is not returning any data but I can't debug this since it returns to the calling code. The builder: property is never executed.

1. What is going on here? Am I right that it is not returning any data?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for any help you can give.

**UPDATE:**

My problem is that _buildEventList returns a widget but it is called in _onDaySelected where there is not build property.

So, I guess my question changes to how do I put this inside the build property so when I click on a day that has events associated to it so the listview is created?

Here is where the build property is in the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId)
                .collection('events')
                .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
                .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              // Handle any errors
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Error fetching data: ${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              }

              // Handle loading data
              debugPrint('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                  List<Events> eventsList = [];
                  for (var snapshotEvent in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                    Events event =
                        Events.fromJson(snapshotEvent.id, snapshotEvent.data());
                    eventsList.add(event);
                  }
                  return _buildTableCalendar(eventsList);
                } else {
                  return _buildTableCalendar();
                }
              }
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          //_buildButtons(),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                showSpinner = true;
              });
              try {
                ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewEvent(true);

                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEventScreen()));

                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = false;
                });
              } catch (e) {
                // todo: add better error handling
                //print(e);
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Add Event'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          //Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the _buildTableCalendar function:

```
Widget _buildTableCalendar([List<Events>? events, List<Trxn>? trxns]) {
    CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
    return TableCalendar(
      firstDay: kFirstDay,
      lastDay: kLastDay,
      focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
      selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
      locale: 'en_US',
      eventLoader: (day) {
        return _getEventsForDay(day, events ?? []);
      },
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        isTodayHighlighted: true,
        selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrange[400]),
        todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrange[200]),
        markerDecoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
      ),
      calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
      onFormatChanged: (format) {
        if (format != _calendarFormat) {
          setState(() {
            _calendarFormat = format;
          });
        }
      },
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonVisible: false,
        titleCentered: true,
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            const TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle:
          const DaysOfWeekStyle(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber)),
      onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedDay = selectedDay;
          _focusedDay = focusedDay; // update `_focusedDay` here as well
          return _onDaySelected(selectedDay, focusedDay);
        });
      },
      onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First You check a offical documents and a offical github example Repository, there exist many useful example in flutter table_calendar
[table_calendar good example](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart).

Base on that Example, You can solved your question using ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder Widget.
this code example in below, that is my code in My own Project using table_calender flutter.

1. add _selecteEvent variable to ValueNotifier, this variable is if you click calendar, _selectedDay is changed and if _selectedDay is changed, you update _selectedEvent variable with ValueNotifier. `_selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(_selectedDay!));` 
    `_getEventsforday` method

```dart
List<Post> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    return kEvents[day] ?? [];
  }
```

that method is just get a Event I saved in Map Structure.

2. Place the ValueListenableBuilder in build method wherever you want.  most important thing in ValueListenableBuilder is assigning `_selectedEvents` to `valueListenable:` property in ValueListenableBuilder

```dart
Expanded(
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Post>>(
          valueListenable: _selectedEvents,
          builder: (context, value, _) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: value.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 12.0,
                    vertical: 4.0,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  PostModal(post: value[index])));
                    },
                    title: Text('${value[index]}'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

PS): In my Project, I used flutter firebase to, so Add Example code my Project for your help.

```dart
void getFirebasePosts() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
        await db.collection("posts").get();
    for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
      Map<String, dynamic> postData = element.data();
      Timestamp firebaseDate = postData["date"];
      DateTime postDate = DateTime.parse(firebaseDate.toDate().toString());
      Post newPostObj = Post(
          title: postData["title"],
          content: postData["content"],
          date: postDate,
          people: postData["people"],
          photos: postData["photos"]);
      setState(() {
        if (kEvents.containsKey(postDate)) {
          kEvents[postDate]!.add(newPostObj);
        } else {
          kEvents[postDate] = [newPostObj];
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getFirebasePosts();
    _selectedDay = _focusedDay;
    _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(_selectedDay!));
  }
```